# Removing two files from a directory upon exit

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to remove all .csv files that are generated in the directory upon exiting the program, also all files that have the name less, less has no extension its just a file called less that appears in the directory. My program works that it removes all the .csv files, but I cannot remove the less file that appears. This is what I have tried:

```
var fs   = require("fs"),
    path = require("path");

function getUserHome() {
  return process.env[(process.platform==='win32')?'USERPROFILE':'HOME']+path.sep;
}

process.on('exit', function() {
    fs.readdirSync(getUserHome() + ".ssh/project").forEach(function(fileName) {
        console.log(fileName);
        if (path.extname(fileName) === ".csv") {
            fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
        }
    });
});
```

This removes all the .csv files.

I want it to also remove the less file so I tried

```
var fs   = require("fs"),
    path = require("path");

function getUserHome() {
  return process.env[(process.platform==='win32')?'USERPROFILE':'HOME']+path.sep;
}

process.on('exit', function() {
    fs.readdirSync(getUserHome() + ".ssh/project").forEach(function(fileName) {
        console.log(fileName);
        if (path.extname(fileName) === ".csv" || path.extname(fileName) === "less" ) {
            fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
        }
    });
});
```

That did not work so I also tried

```
var fs   = require("fs"),
    path = require("path");

function getUserHome() {
  return process.env[(process.platform==='win32')?'USERPROFILE':'HOME']+path.sep;
}

process.on('exit', function() {
    fs.readdirSync(getUserHome() + ".ssh/project").forEach(function(fileName) {
        console.log(fileName);
        if (path.extname(fileName) === ".csv") {
            fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
        }
         if (path.extname(fileName) === "less") {
            fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
        }
    });
});
```

That also did not work, in both cases they just remove all the .csv files, but I also want to remove less file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to add `dirpath` to `filename`. You also forgot to add `.` when you check file with `less` filename.

This should work

```
var fs   = require("fs"),
    path = require("path");

function getUserHome() {
  return process.env[(process.platform==='win32')?'USERPROFILE':'HOME']+path.sep;
}

process.on('exit', function() {
    fs.readdirSync(getUserHome() + ".ssh/project").forEach(function(fileName) {

        console.log(fileName);
        if (path.extname(fileName) === ".csv" || fileName === "less" ) {

            // prepend path to file name
            fs.unlinkSync(getUserHome() + ".ssh/project/" + fileName);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it is not a .less extension, it just a file that is called less

it has not extension at all

Comment: Ok then just checked only name of it.